# Java MapReduce doesn't work

Tags: java, hadoop, map-reduce

Не понимаю почему не импортируются библиотеки Hadoop. Classpath установил вроде правильно, но всё равно ошибки.

[image: Подключенный путь]

[image: Ошибки в процессе компиляции]

Comment: `Classpath установил вроде правильно` - нет, не правильно. Открой `hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-3.0.0.jar` и посмотри есть ли там все указанные тобой классы. Спойлер: нет. Поэтому javac и ругается. Если сам не разберешься маякни потом - вечером тогда ответ напишу.(пока что времени не особо хватает)